# Boost.Asio asynchronous server. Limit to one connection

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I'm fairly new to Boost.Asio and I want to develop an asynchronous server that limits the number of active connections to one.  In other words, when a connection is established, additional connections will be denied.  Once that connection is closed, another one can take its spot.

It's not immediately clear how to accomplish this and still be able to re-connect if the connection gets closed.

Could someone provide a simple example of how to do this?

EDIT:  How would you take the Boost.Asio Asynchronous Server [example code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) and edit it to limit the number of connections?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't accept the new connection until the previous is done.

Simplest possible program I can come up with:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CHRONO 1
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

class Server {
    ba::io_service _svc;
    tcp::acceptor _acc{_svc};
    tcp::socket _conn{_svc};

    ba::streambuf _request, _response;

  public:
    void start(unsigned short port, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration time) {
        _acc.open(tcp::v4());
        _acc.bind({{}, port});
        _acc.listen(5);

        do_accept();

        _svc.run_for(time);
    }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        if (_conn.is_open())
            _conn.close();

        _acc.async_accept(_conn, [=](error_code ec) { handle_accept(ec); });
    }

    void handle_accept(error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) std::cout << "Accepted: " << _conn.remote_endpoint() << ", " << ec << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
        else     std::cout << "Accepted, " << ec << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";

        ba::async_read_until(_conn, _request, "\r\n", [=](error_code ec, size_t xfr) { handle_read(ec, xfr); });
    }

    void handle_read(error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
        std::cout << "Read request: " << transferred << " bytes, " << ec << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";

        std::vector<char> v(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&_request), {});
        std::reverse_copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(&_response));

        ba::async_write(_conn, _response, [=](error_code ec, size_t xfr) { handle_write(ec, xfr); });
    }

    void handle_write(error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
        std::cout << "Written request: " << transferred << " bytes, " << ec << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";

        do_accept(); // ONLY HERE initiate new accept. Could be back-log pending
    }
};

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
int main() {
    Server s;

    s.start(6767, 3s); // For demo, run 3 seconds
}
```

Prints

```
./sotest & sleep .5; for w in Hello Bye; do echo -ne "$w world\!\\r\\n" | netcat localhost 6767; done
Accepted: 127.0.0.1:43764, system:0 (Success)
Read request: 15 bytes, system:0 (Success)

!\dlrow olleHWritten request: 15 bytes, system:0 (Success)
Accepted: 127.0.0.1:43766, system:0 (Success)
Read request: 13 bytes, system:0 (Success)

!\dlrow eyBWritten request: 13 bytes, system:0 (Success)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I was asking for since the connection is being explicitly closed by the program on each iteration.  I want it to keep it open and only re-connect if the client disconnects and wants to connect again.  I still want to thank you since your answer led me to figuring out how to do what I was asking.  I'm still evaluating it and I may end up posting the code here.

Comment: @RicardoAngeli That's merely the demo, right. You **can** wait until the connection is dropped. Even then it's /nice/ to make sure the socket isn't in the open state (otherwise, you'd need a new instance to accept a new connection on)

Comment: Here's, to drive the point home, a version that makes it clear there is no need to forcibly close a socket: [on coliru¹](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb1185f894c3a521). I just test it by pointing `netcat -C` at it - [demo vid (4.6Mb)](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/4f25141b-6e6b-49da-bce6-a7f2507865aa/demo.mp4) (¹ boost version is out of date so it doesn't support `run_for`).